# IntelliJ Run app configuration for Grails

Tags: jetbrains-ide

[image]

From the screenshot, how do I set the environment variable for the Grails to run on development? Any tips on Grails deploying through IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, "run-app" will run on development.

If you want different environment to run, for example test environment, then use

```
test run-app
```

If you have custom environment, then use

```
-Dgrails.env=customeEnv run-app
```